# Updating asset indexes doesn't work

Tags: craft3, tasks

I have a page where updating the asset indexes is not working.

If I hit «Update asset indexes» The loading animation shows and never stops the animation.

- Installed [AsyncQueue](https://github.com/ostark/craft-async-queue) = Same effect
- Increased memory_limit to 128M
- max_execution_time is set to 30
- There are no stuck tasks
- php 7.0.33
- CraftCMS 3.15

It works locally (MAMP Apache) so I guess it must be a server thing?!

There are about 10 pdf & jpg assets so it's not a lot.

What else can I do?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your Javascript or Network console? You can also index assets from the cli tool using this command: ./craft index-assets/all

Comment: Are you using a remote volume like S3 and storing the access keys as .env vars, and did you forget to populate them after deploying to a new environment? Because that’s what I just did.

Comment: No remote volume like s3